# Alias a rails controller and have generated urls point to the alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to alias a rails controller and have `url_for()` generate urls to the alias.

Like this:

```
map.resources :original, :as => :alias
```

In views and controllers I would like urls to use `alias` not `original`

```
url_for(:controller => 'alias')
```

Generates:

```
"/alias" not "/original"
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the :path option for routing.

Also, I think it would be more elegant to use alias_path instead of url_for